# Got strange in BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, gridview, baseadapter

It should be simple part of app with GridView and Images in it, when button click go to camera, capture new photo and add it to GridView

Here I'm apply ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter

```
partItem = getPart(position);

StaticGridView gridView = (StaticGridView) view.findViewById(R.id.ImagesGrid);
imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(mContext, partItem.P_Code, partItem.Images);
gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

**ImageAdapter.java**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    public Map<Integer, String> partImages;
    public String P_Code;

    private static final String TAG = "ImageAdapter";

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, String _P_Code, Map<Integer, String> _partImages) {
        this.mContext = c;
        this.partImages = _partImages;
        this.P_Code = _P_Code;
    }

    public void changeModelList(Map<Integer, String> _partImages) {
        partImages = _partImages;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return partImages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return partImages.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, GridView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(API.ApiUrlBase + "/imagepreview/android" + getItem(position))
                    .placeholder(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery)
                    .into(imageView);

            Log.d(TAG, position + ":" + String.valueOf(getItem(position)));

        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        return imageView;
    }

}
```

got in log

```
: 1:/data/44452.P1090185.JPG
: 2:/data/44452.P1090186.JPG
: 3:/data/44452.P1090187.JPG
: 0:/data/44452.P1090184.JPG
: 0:/data/44452.P1090184.JPG
```

it's ok becose of Picasso, but when i try to add new image

```
partItem.Images.put(imageAdapter.getCount(), mCurrentPhotoPath);
// imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
imageAdapter.changeModelList(partItem.Images);
```

got in log

```
{
  4=file:/storage/sdcard/Pictures/JPEG_20160306_213748_1027396172.jpg,
  1=/data/44452.P1090185.JPG,
  0=/data/44452.P1090184.JPG,
  3=/data/44452.P1090187.JPG,
  2=/data/44452.P1090186.JPG
}
: 0:/data/44452.P1090184.JPG
```

and first image appears at the GridView but there is no new file.
Is anyone have an idea?
[GridView screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILAws.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So simple...
I gues BaseAdapter can't work with HashMap
changed this

```
public Map<Integer, String> partImages;
```

to this

```
public ArrayList partImages;
```